# Cannot set request timeout over 1 minute with Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, timeout

I am using Node.js v16 with express v4. I am trying to increase the HTTP request timout.

I used the recommendations in the documentation and in the threads I found here. The thing is, when I set the timeout to be lower than 1 minute, it works. When I set it to be higher than 1 minute, it always times out after 1 minute.

I tried several code options, didn't work. I am not using any AWS LB or CloudFront, so it's a direct call. Any idea what could cause this 1m timeout?

Comment: can you add links to the question? server.setTimeout should work. Or you can use connect-timeout package

Comment: used both. As I said - under a minute it worked, over a minute - it timed out after 1m

Comment: It maybe because of the firewall configuration. In some situations, the firewall in your network is dropping the connections by timeout response when it is more than a particular time. try to disable it and if it works, please let me know